# VBA move character to next column

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a code that If `column A` contains **REG** then move it over to `column B` and remove it from `A`.

*For example:*

If, **`A1 = tsf - REG`** *and* **`B1 is empy`**

Then, as a result, I'd like to see my cells as below:

**`A1=tsf`**  *and*  **`B1=REG`**

How can I write code for this kind of purpose?

Comment: Is there always a hyphen ?

Answer (score -1):

```
Option Explicit
----------------------------------------------------
Sub moveReg()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(3).Row

Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To lastRow

    Range("A" & i).Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False

    Dim str As String, reg As String
    str = Range("A" & i).Value
    reg = "REG"

    Dim indexOfREG As Integer
    indexOfREG = InStr(1, str, reg, vbTextCompare)

    Dim finalString As String
    finalString = Left(str, Len(str) - indexOfREG + 1)

    Dim REGString As String
    REGString = Right(str, (Len(reg)))

    Range("A" & i).Value = finalString
    Range("B" & i).Value = REGString

    i = i + 1

Next

End Sub
```